# How to render Emojis natively in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, emoji

I'm building a Meteor application that pulls Tweets and Instagram photos, stores relevant data from them into MongoDB, and then renders them out from the database onto the frontend.

Emojis in these Tweets display fine on Safari, Firefox and on my iPhone. However, they do not display at all in Chrome (I'm using a webfont, 'Roboto Condensed'. If I switch to `font-family: sans-serif;`, they display as an empty rectangle box: `⚳`).

How can I get these Emojis to render properly on Chrome?

I'm aware of libraries such as [Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji), but I would prefer a solution that can make them display natively instead of switching them out for an `<img>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing `font-weight: bold;` from the `div` containing the Emoji's, they were able to render correctly in Chrome.